# How to change Windows password without changing Microsoft Account password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, passwords, user-accounts

A couple of months ago, I purchased a HP Desktop, which runs Windows 10.

During the initial Windows 10 setup, I was asked to create a Microsoft Account.  This Microsoft Account was then going to be used to log into Windows.

Once the Microsoft Account was set up, I was then taken to a page which asked if I wanted to create a password that was specific to this Desktop only.  This being a security measure, so that I could give people the password to the computer, which is linked to my Microsoft Account, without revealing the Microsoft Account password as well.

I went ahead and did this, which allowed me to log into Windows (Which is linked to my Microsoft Account) with the 'device specific' password.  I have been using this password for a couple of months now, with no issues.

That was until today.  I tried to log in and it stated that the password was incorrect.  The only password, Windows was accepting, was the Microsoft Account password.  I tried to change the password but this changed the Microsoft Account password.  In simple terms, I no longer have a separate password for this computer.

I have spoken with Microsoft but they say that there is no way to have a separate password for the computer, unless I use a Local Account. I stated that I did not have a Local Account before and that I simply had a Microsoft Account linked to my Windows setup, which accepted a password designated to just this device.  Despite my assurances that I have set up these passwords on several Desktops, via the Windows 10 setup page, I was told that such a feature did not exist.

As such, I was wondering if anyone else had come across this or indeed was also aware of this feature and was able to give some guidance on how I can go ahead and change the password for Windows without it changing the Microsoft Account password.

Comment: I am not sure where the initial guidance came from. A Microsoft Account has one password for any device using that Account, and you change it on the Microsoft Live web page for your account. Otherwise, you need to change to a Local Account. I have 3 machines, two with a Microsoft Account and one password for this Account. The third machine has a local account and a different name and password unique to that machine. In your case, you must change the Microsoft Account Password.

Comment: It was during the Windows 10 setup screen.  Once I setup a Microsoft Account, the screen requested me to create a password that was unique to my device.  Until today, I had been able to log into my device, with its unique password.  All the emails, associated with the Microsoft Account, were being received fine too.  Could it had been a feature specific with HP?

Comment: The comments I made were Microsoft and not for a specific machine. I do not know what HP might have done.

Comment: Was this a password or a pin? Because I have installed hundreds of Windows 10 installations and I have never heard what you describe.   The only password to a local account that can be used that is linked to a Microsoft Account is the password to that account

Comment: @John ... Thinking about it, I do not think it is a HP feature as I have an older Acer laptop too where I am able to still log into Windows (Which is linked to the same Microsoft Account) but with a different password.

Comment: @Ramhound .  It is a Password.  I do have a PIN set up too though.  As per my previous comment, I have just switched on my other computer, where I can log into Windows still, with the unique password assigned to that computer.  In other words, I have 2 computers.  Both synced with the same Microsoft Account but with 2 different passwords to log in with.  Up until today, one of the devices is not accepting the unique password.  Only the Microsoft Account password.

Comment: @Craig - You are sure both local accounts are still linked to the Microsoft Account.  I have more than 5 machines connected to my own MS account.  I have never heard of what you describe.  I simply use my MS password to log into my account.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone stumbling on this question, here's a bit of clarification, because I couldn't find documentation or clarification on this myself:

[image: screenshot of windows 10 sign in settings]

↑ Windows 10 sign in settings

"Password" is not your *Windows* password, that is your Microsoft account password. I'm not sure, but I think they may have changed the wording of these options recently, which confused me.

"Windows Hello pin" is actually what you would think of as your computer's/Windows password. It's confusing because the wording and icon makes it seem like it can only be numbers, but once you try to set it, you'll see an option to include letters:

[image: make a new pin dialog]

So in short, creating a pin is how you make a Windows password separate from your Microsoft account.

---

In response to one of the comments above:

> I have never heard of what you describe. I simply use my MS password to log into my account.

My Microsoft password is long and complex, and managed by a password manager. It's an account that has sensitive information like product licenses and CC numbers.

My Windows password needs to be quick and easy to type so I can get in quickly, so it has to be short and simple. (Before anyone flames me, I have sensitive info on my computer in VeraCrypt drives, plus you generally assume game over if someone gains long term physical access to your computer because they can do offline attacks or can beat the password out of you.)

They're two different standards of security and shouldn't have to be the same password.